# Regex Pattern to check only letters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check whether string is only contain letters but not numbers or special characters.I used below regex pattern,

```
String validText = "^[a-zA-Z-]+$";
```

its work fine for 'Leo#' but if it is like 'Leo#1' its not working properly.

Anyone have idea ?

Comment: Try:  "^[-a-zA-z]+$".

Comment: Your pattern should be `^[a-zA-Z]+$`. You have an extra hyphen that will match `-` literally. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: @Gordon : its same not working for 'Leo#1'

Comment: By "not working for Leo#1", you mean that "Leo#1" should be invalid and your current regex is considering it valid?

Comment: @everton : it is my mistake...it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you can use LinQ (input is your test string)

```
bool result = input.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

Else as Gordon Posted the right Regex,

```
^[a-zA-z]+$
```

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: Your regex is wrong. I like the LINQ option personally, though. Not sure how performance compares.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regex

**/^[A-Za-z]+$/**

This will match only letters in your string ..